# Laravel Password Resets - Argument #1 ($password) must be of type string

Tags: laravel

I follow the guide to resetting a password from the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords)

```
 $status = Password::reset(
        $request->only('email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'),
        function ($user, $password) {
            $user->forceFill([
                'password' => Hash::make($password)
            ])->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

            $user->save();

            event(new PasswordReset($user));
        }
    );
```

Yet I get the error:

> password_verify(): Argument #1 ($password) must be of type string, array given

Answer (score -1):

The `password` in the request object is somehow coming as an array. Put `dd($request)` on your controller, and you'll see that. In the view file I think you have mistakenly set the password field's name as "password[]" instead.